# How to completely automate the node js server switching on/off process

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, automation, server

I have developed an application using express js. In order the automate the process, I created a jenkins job and the commands used are as follows

```html
ssh "ip address of the server" node app.js "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" &
curl "url of the application"
curl "another url of the application"
```

Here a,b,c,d,e are the command line arguments which i am passing to my application on starting the server. The problem is each time i have to shutdown the server first and then run the job. How can this whole process be automated and also server should keep on running in background.
Please let me know if anyone want some more clarification on the question asked. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: you have reached the stage where you should use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to keep server running

Comment: Ok i can use this but the point is, if i want to change my arguments and run the  job again then in that case i have to first manually shut down the server and then trigger the job. How to get rid of this problem.

Comment: see my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1**  Get rid of passing args by:

***option 1***

use `npm` scripts in `package.json` with `forever`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "forever express/app.js a b c"
  },
```

Command to run your server `npm start`

***option 2***

use `bat` or `sh` file to restart your app

*file.bat* content

```
forever express/app.js a b c
```

*automate.js*

```
var automaton = require('automaton').create();
automaton.run('run', {cmd: 'file.bat'}).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Command to run your server `node automate`

**Step2** Configure forever code to run `npm start` or `node automate` whenever some change is found in `package.json` or `file.bat`, respectively

**See it in action**, clone [Git Repo](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/express) and run `node express\index.js` or run `npm start`

Happy Helping!

Comment: did the answer help you any way?

Comment: your answer is correct, but the point is i am passing different parameters. Say for test1 parameters are a,b,c and for test2 it is d,e,f. What could be done in this case??, i.e how to deal with multiple parameters and automate the entire process.

Comment: okay, if answer is correct please mark it correct, AND automate never means magic :) no matter how efficient process you write but `arguments` are supposed to be passed this way or that way (while starting server or from some file).